# How can I possibly Backup LocalDB deployed by ClickOnce programmatically

Tags: sql, vb.net, backup, clickonce, localdb

I am trying to write VB.Net Code to programmatically backup LocalDB, that is deployed by ClickOnce, using BACKUP DATABASE command in SQL. My requirement is to back-up the DB upon user request (on button click).

As the mdf file in ClickOnce deployment lies in an obfuscated path(appdata/app/version/data/obfuscated_folder_names/database_name.mdf) I am unable to pass database name to backup command.

When I pass database name as string in

```
BACKUP DATABASE obfuscated_string TO DISK=@destination,
```

I get an error message that identifier is too long (more than 128 characters).

Alternately, when I pass database name as varchar(max) parameter,

```
BACKUP DATABASE @FullPathofDatabase TO DISK=@destination
```

I get an error message that the database does not exist, which is because actual database name in sys.databases is a truncated portion of physical_name in sys.master_files.

Is there a method to back-up LocalDB, if at all or is this behaviour by design?

Comment: What os `obfuscated_string`, is that a path or a database name?

Comment: The string is the path to the mdf file. Mdf file lies in a folder with obfuscated path while deployed by clickonce